# Extjs - Dock Button to bottom of the Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I want to align **Credentials** button to the bottom of the panel in `extjs`, Is there any specific property to do that only for buttons inside the panel. No toolbar involvement is here:

[image]

Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/arya9/rmad2cpb/

Comment: Post your code or put it in fiddle so that we can help you with your problem

Comment: here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/arya9/rmad2cpb/

Comment: That fiddle does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle.
You just need to add that button in dockedItems of Panel

```
{
        xtype: 'panel',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout: 'vbox',
        height: 400,
        padding: 20,
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'button',
            margin: '0 0 12 0'
        },

        items: [{
            text: 'Normal Button'

        }, {
            text: 'Basic Button'
        }],

        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            dock: 'bottom',
            text: 'Docked Button',
            margin: '0 0 12 0'
        }]
    }
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/25aa

Answer (score 0):

Hope this below code will help you as per your requirement.

```
 Ext.create('Ext.Window',{
        width:200,
        height:400,
        layout:'vbox',
        items:[{
         xtype:'button',
         text:'First'
        },{
          xtype:'panel',
          flex:1
        },{
         xtype:'button',
         text:'Second'
        }]
    }).show();
```

You can check here in sencha fiddle it is working https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/25a9

Answer (score 0):

Use a toolbar and change xtype: '**spacer**' for xtype: '**tbfill**'